# create multiple data store in indexeddb

Tags: indexeddb

I want to create **multiple data store** in one database in indexeddb.

I have created my database - **College**

Created a data store - **Student**

In the "**College**" database I want to create one more data store **dynamically** with the name "**Department**".

Is it possible? Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In IndexedDB, a [database](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-database) can contain as many [object stores](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-object-store) as you'd like. So having "Department" and "Student" stores inside of a "College" database is no problem at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am new to indexeddb, can you please provide me some link or syntax for creating multiple object store dynamically.

Comment: Here's the `maybeAddObjectStore()` method from [dash](http://dashdb.com/#docs), my IDB wrapper https://github.com/editor/dash/blob/master/lib/dash.dev.js#L915

Comment: No problem! Anything else I can help with to nudge you toward marking this as "correct"?

Comment: I refer the link which u provided and one more link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097662/how-to-create-multiple-objectstores-in-indexeddb", But getting error, DOM Exception, for which I have already posted a question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604556/domexception-at-the-time-of-opendatabase-with-higher-version

Comment: Different question - different answer. I answered that one as well though: we need some more info about your error (such as `error.message` and the stack)

Comment: I am getting DOM Exception here is what I am getting in console.  `DBOpenDBRequest {onupgradeneeded: null, onblocked: null, onerror: null, onsuccess: null, readyState: "pending"…}
  error: [Exception: DOMException]
  onblocked: function () { console.log("blocked..."); }
  onerror: function () { console.log("error..."); }
  onsuccess: function () { console.log("success .. "); }
  onupgradeneeded: function (e2) {
  readyState: "pending"
  result: [Exception: DOMException]
  source: null
  transaction: null
 __proto__: IDBOpenDBRequest`

Comment: I know this is an old one, but the key fact here is as statet at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/createObjectStore : *This method can be called only within a versionchange transaction.* . Very fooolish if u ask me :/