# DOMException at the time of opendatabase with higher version

Tags: indexeddb

I want to create **multiple datastore**, So I found solution that I can do this on **version change.**

So I wrote following

```
var request = indexedDB.open(dbName);
    request.onsuccess = function (e){
        var db = e.target.result;
        var version = db.version;
        db.close();

        var request2 = indexedDB.open(dbName , ++version);
        console.log(request2);   //Error on this line

        request2.onsuccess = function() { console.log("success .. "); };
        request2.onerror = function() { console.log("error..."); };
        request2.onblocked = function() { console.log("blocked..."); };
        request2.onupgradeneeded = function(e2) { 
            //Will creaate new datastore here
        };
    }
```

---

when I open database with higher version it is giving following error "**error: [Exception: DOMException]**"

```
DBOpenDBRequest {onupgradeneeded: null, onblocked: null, onerror: null, onsuccess: null, readyState: "pending"…}
  error: [Exception: DOMException]
  onblocked: function () { console.log("blocked..."); }
  onerror: function () { console.log("error..."); }
  onsuccess: function () { console.log("success .. "); }
  onupgradeneeded: function (e2) {
  readyState: "pending"
  result: [Exception: DOMException]
  source: null
  transaction: null
 __proto__: IDBOpenDBRequest
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some more information about the exception it self? the content of the result please.

Comment: Actually in content of result is "[Exception: DOMException]" only.

Comment: That is an object you should be able to inspect the field and get more information about the exception. Is it also possible to provide an example of the content in the onupgradeneeded event? In which browser are you currently testing?

Comment: I have attached screen shot of the error. It is not an Object, and I am not able to inspect that.

Comment: I am working on chrome browser Version 33.0.1750.152

Comment: I think it is your version field that is the issue, see my awnser

Answer (score 2):

I think the version property is probably the issue. Are you sure it has a value. A DOM Exception occures when opening the db when the value of version is 0 or a negative number. For more info see [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-IndexedDB-20111206/#widl-IDBFactory-open-IDBOpenDBRequest-DOMString-name-unsigned-long-long-version)

When you are trying to open the db again with a higher version, you get a blocked event.

Try adding the following to the db object.

```
db.onversionchange = function (event) { event.target.close(); }
```

This will close the current connection. So the upgrade of the db can proceed. When upgrading the db you can't have any open connections.

Comment: Thanks for immediate response. But version has value, while opening database second time I have incremented that value.

Comment: Are you a 100% sure? Try putting a brakepoint and check if it works fine.

Comment: Yes Kristof Degrave, I have added breakpoints. First time I am creating database with version 2 after that I have incremented it now it becomes 3.

Comment: In your screenshot of the console, I see a blocked... appear. Maybe you have another connection that is open? Add a blocked event handler to the request object (the one resulting from indexeddb.open(dbName)). And in the callback add logic to close the connection.

Comment: blocked... message is appearing for second request.                 `var request2 = indexedDB.open(dbName , ++version);
        console.log(request2);   //Error on this line

        request2.onsuccess = function() { console.log("success .. "); };
        request2.onerror = function() { console.log("error..."); };
        request2.onblocked = function() { console.log("blocked..."); };`

Comment: Ok, well that means that you have open connections. Try to add a onversionchange to the db object. And when that occures, close the database connection. The onversionchange callback is called when you try to open the db in a higher version, but your current connection is still in the older version.

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting your point. When should I open new db with higher version? and when should I add onversionchange()?

Comment: You can stay working like you do now, but you should add the onversionchange callback in all the success results of a db.open call

Comment: And what happens if you just remove console.log(request2);

Comment: It was not executing success and onupgradeneeded block, for debugging purpose I have added console.log(request2);

Answer (score 2):

Your IDB is fine. It looks like you have a scoping issue inside of your second `success` callback. I found `request2` object to be undefined but the request itself is fine.

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/B6XvL/) stripped down to the core issue (the second `IDBOpenRequest`) - when executing this you'll see the version increment on each run.

```
var dbName = 'User780611',
  request = indexedDB.open(dbName);

request.onsuccess = function (e) {
  var db = e.target.result;
  var version = db.version;
  db.close();
  var request2 = indexedDB.open(dbName, ++
    version);
  request2.onsuccess = function () {
    window.document.getElementById('User780611').innerHTML = this.result.version;
  };
}
```

Comment: It is working on fiddle, but I am getting the same error when i run on my application.

Comment: Then the error is happening outside of the code you've posted. Are you using `this` to reference the request in your application code? It's a good way to avoid the scoping issue I see.

Comment: `createStore: function (iObj) {
     var indexedDB = this.idb;
     var dbName = this.dbName;
     var request = indexedDB.open(dbName);
     request.onsuccess = function (e) {
      var db = e.target.result;
      var version = db.version;
      db.close();
      var request2 = indexedDB.open(dbName, ++version);
      console.log(request2);
      request2.onsuccess = function () {
        //window.document.getElementById('User780611').innerHTML = this.result.version;
       console.log(this.result.version);
      };
    }
    }`     Here is my function to create object store.

Comment: Not helpful unfortunately. Without being able to reproduce the error we're not going to get far in helping you. What does the `request.error` object look like logged out? Try looking at `request.error.message` and `request.error.stack` - interested in what `DOMException` we're talking about here.

Comment: I have attach the screen shot, can you please take a look into that.

Comment: I have, very closely. `[Exception: DOMException]` is a stringification of your error and not the error object itself. It tells us very little about which error you're seeing - just that it's of the type `DOMException`. [There are about a dozen possible errors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabaseException).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the printout of request 2 gives an error because it is still busy either opening the db or calling the upgradeneeded. I think 
- if you remove console.log(request2); 
- Put a try catch around the code 
- Put console.log into all callbacks you will see what is happening.

```
var request = indexedDB.open(dbName);
request.onsuccess = function (e){
    var db = e.target.result;
    var version = db.version;
    db.onversionchange = function () { console.log("version change ...."); };
    db.close();

    try
    {
       var request2 = indexedDB.open(dbName , ++version);
       //console.log(request2);   //Error on this line

       request2.onsuccess = function() { console.log("success .. "); };
       request2.onerror = function() { console.log("error..."); };
       request2.onblocked = function() { console.log("blocked..."); };
       request2.onupgradeneeded = function(e2) { 
           //Will creaate new datastore here
           console.log("upgradeneeded...");
       };
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
        console.log(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is printing out "blocked..."

Comment: This means you have an connection that is still open

Comment: But I am closing the database. In onsucess method I have written db.close();

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same issue. As Kristof said, 'Blocked' message means there are open connections. So the reason its still appearing despite the `db.close()` in the first request.onsuccess callback means that there is another database still open. Therefore, you need to close that as well before you execute the second request.

Here is how i solved it in order to add object store too:

```
var idb = (function(){

  var idbObj = {};
  var db = null;   //gonna need to close this db later when adding new object store
  const dbName = "collectionDB3";
  var version = 1;

idbObj.open = function(){

      var objectStore;
      var dbRequest = window.indexedDB.open(dbName);

      dbRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event){
        var thisDB = event.target.result;

        if(!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("collection")) {
            objectStore = thisDB.createObjectStore("collection", { keyPath: 'id',   autoIncrement: true });  
        }
        console.log("upgrading", thisDB);
      };


      dbRequest.onsuccess = function(event){

        db = event.target.result;
        version = db.version;

        console.log("opened database", version);
      };

      dbRequest.onerror = function(event){
        console.log("database error ", event.target.errorCode);
      };
  };


 idbObj.addObjectStore = function(storeName){
      db.close();    //this is where the only opened db connection is closed
      var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, version+1);  //increment version to create object store in onupgradeneeded

        request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
          var thisDB = event.target.result;

          if(!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains(storeName)) {
            var objectStore = thisDB.createObjectStore(storeName, { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });   
          }
        };

        request.onsuccess = function (event) {
          db = event.target.result; //update db
          version = db.version;  //update db's version
          console.log("added objectstore", db);
        };

        request.onerror = function(event){
            console.log("database error ", request.error);
        };

   };

    return idbObj;
}());


idb.open();   
createObjectStore();   //test the addObjectStore method see if new object store is created

function createObjectStore(){
  setTimeout(function(){idb.addObjectStore("newStoreName")}, 3000);
}
```

Hope this helps  =)