# Is it possible to create multiple dataStore in angular-localForage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexeddb, localforage

Is it possible to have multiple dataStore in IndexedDB using [angular-localForage](https://github.com/bobsilon/angular-localForage)?

I tried this:

```js
var $tblStage = $localForage.createInstance({
    storeName   : 'tblStage', // name of the table
});
```

but it triggered an error which says:

> Error: A localForage instance with the name dbName is already defined.

I read [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097662/how-to-create-multiple-object-stores-in-indexeddb) before but, is the only way is working with Raw IndexedDB? Or I missed something in my code? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only configure when you use.
https://github.com/mozilla/localForage#configuration

But no its possible two instance at same db.

If you intend to use the directive, local-forage, you'll have to copy and configure it.

Just like this https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage/blob/master/src/angular-localForage.js#L51, for change the provide,
only change defaultConfig at #L20, and name of angular module directive #L465.

And give more information but the reputation is very low and this leaves hook and my English so bad.